# How can I iterate through multiple dataframes to select a column in each in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics, jupyter

For my project I'm reading in a csv file with data from every State in the US. My function converts each of these into a separate Dataframe as I need to perform operations on each State's information.

```
def RanktoDF(csvFile):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile)
    df = df[pd.notnull(df['Index'])] # drop all null values
    df = df[df.Index != 'Index'] #Drop all extra headers
    df= df.set_index('State') #Set State as index
    return df
```

I apply this function to every one of my files and return the df with a name from my array varNames

```
for name , s in zip (glob.glob('*.csv'), varNames):
    vars()["Crime" + s] = RanktoDF(name)
```

All of that works perfectly.
My problem is that I also want to create a Dataframe thats made up of one column from each of those State Dataframes.

I have tried iterating through a list of my dataframes and selecting the column (population) i want to append it to a new Dataframe:

[dfList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD2ec.png)

```
dfNewIndex = pd.DataFrame(index=CrimeRank_1980_df.index) # Create new DF with Index


for name in dfList:  #dfList is my list of dataframes. See image
    newIndex = name['Population']
    dfNewIndex.append(newIndex)

    #dfNewIndex = pd.concat([dfNewIndex, dfList[name['Population']], axis=1)
```

My error is always the same which tells me that name is viewed as a string rather than an actual Dataframe

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5aa85b0174df> in <module>()
      3 
      4 for name in dfList:
----> 5     newIndex = name['Index']
      6     dfNewIndex.append(newIndex)
      7 #     dfNewIndex = pd.concat([dfNewIndex, dfList[name['Population']], axis=1)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I understand that my list is a list of Strings rather than variables/dataframes so my question is how can i correct my code to be able to do what i want or is there an easier way of doing this?

Any solutions I've looked up have given answers where the dataframes are explicitly typed in order to be concatenated but I have 50 so its a little unfeasible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the objects in dfList are of the type dataframe? because it seems to be just the names of said dataframes and then the error makes total sense.

Comment: Are you sure this line works as expected: `df = df[df.Index != 'Index'] #Drop all extra headers`

Comment: @Alexander Yea it does. Its a quirk of my CSV file that Its an amalgamation of 3 tables stacked on top of each other.They have the same headers so by removing 'Index' from the Index column I remove all those other headers and am left with just the first one. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Aquiles Yea you're totally correct. I recognise that myself at the bottom of my post but was just having trouble getting around it so to speak. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to index into vars(), e.g.

```
for name in dfList:
    newIndex = vars()[name]["Population"]
```

Alternatively I think it would be neater to store your dataframes in a container and iterate through that, e.g.

```
frames = {}

for name, s in zip(glob.glob('*.csv'), varNames):
    frames["Crime" + s] = RanktoDF(name)

for name in frames:
    newIndex = frames[name]["Population"]
```

Comment: Upvote is for second approach.  You can also use a dictionary comprehension:  `frames = {"Crime" + s: RanktoDF(name) for name, s in zip(glob.glob.('*.csv'), varNames)}`

Comment: @James thats great thank you so much. I'll use the container as well it makes much more sense that way. Appreciate the help