# iterating in a list of dataframe names with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframes defined, they have data (floats) and their names are:

```
df_names = ['df_correl_USDCOP','df_correl_USDCLP','df_correl_USDRUB']
```

I also have defined the following lists to be able to plot using a loop:

```
figures = ['fig'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df_names))]
axes    = ['ax'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df_names))]

for fig, ax, name in zip(figures,axes,df_names):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))
    ax.plot(name[:],lw=4)
```

when doing this, an error appears as in the loop the dataframe is not recognized as such, but just as a string.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: df_correl_USDCOP
```

I was checking this answer, [How can I iterate through multiple dataframes to select a column in each in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601956/how-can-i-iterate-through-multiple-dataframes-to-select-a-column-in-each-in-pyth/36602132) but wasn't able to apply it to this example.

The question is not regarding the plotting itself, but how to iterate trough the dataframe name list and get the "actual" dataframe and not a string with its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the actual dataframes and not strings with their names into a second list.

If the rest of the code is OK (which I cannot test without data), it should work if you use the following instead:

```
df_names = ['df_correl_USDCOP','df_correl_USDCLP','df_correl_USDRUB']
df_list = [df_correl_USDCOP,df_correl_USDCLP,df_correl_USDRUB]

figures = ['fig'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df_names))]
axes    = ['ax'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df_names))]

for fig, ax, name in zip(figures,axes,df_list):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))
    ax.plot(name[:],lw=4)
```